# Angular back button dont refresh the view im going to be

Tags: angular

i have some issues figuring out this. I have a side bar with categories, the user choose one or the other but if he uses the back button the url changes but the view does not

I'm doing this on `sideBar.ts` because if i go normally the view does not update, found this work around but when i go back view doesn't update

```
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/categorias/${categoryName}/${parentProductCategoryId}`)  
  });
```

`categories.ts`

```
  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
    onPopState(event) {
      // should i refresh the view here?
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refresh the view manually. Angular should do it automatically (:

Most likely you have a code for reading `categoryName` and `parentProductCategoryId` from the query string and use it to render the view. I guess that you do it without subscribing to the URL changes. So that when the next time the query params changed the component doesn't notice it and shows the previous view.

Also would be great to check the console. There could be some errors.

If you could provide stackblitz with reproduction, it would be great